# Lenovo Legion 5 randomly kills entire wifi network

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, lenovo-laptop

I have this new Lenovo Legion 5 laptop. Since day 1, I've been having this very specific problem. It will consistently kill the wifi router in my house. It kills the wifi signal on every device that is connected to it. The issue isn't with the wireless router itself, since that doesn't happen with the multiple devices that I have connected to the router.

The wifi card isn't the issue, because when the laptop goes offline, so does everything else in my house. And when I'm not using the laptop, this isn't a problem. For the record, the operating system is Windows 10. I mistakenly thought it was an issue with the wireless card and had a lenovo technician replace it a few weeks ago. This did not alleviate the problem.

Comment: Since the laptop is new, it likely has an AC Wireless Card. Try limiting it to "N"  and see if that works better.

Comment: Can you quantify "kills the signal"? Are you saying everyone's signal strength bars drop to zero bars? Or are you saying their bars stay lit but their network performance struggles? If the latter, can you measure what kind of a speed drop you're talking about? Also, what does it take to clear the problem? Just disabling Wi-Fi on the Lenovo? Or do you have to reboot the router?

Comment: @Spiff everyone drops to zero bars and the connection is lost entirely. I can't really do anything to fix the problem. The connection will come back on its own after a period of time before dropping again later on.

Comment: @John I can't limit it to "N". Just n/ac/ax.

Comment: I suggest you get a USB Wireless card, flexible enough to be dual band N and AC.  Disable your on-board wireless and install the Wireless USB card. That should solve your issues.

Comment: @Alphatron it sounds like the Lenovo laptop is doing something that your AP (wireless router) is choking on and crashing and rebooting because of (like maybe your new laptop supports Wi-Fi 6, and your AP is buggy and can't deal with a client trying to negotiate Wi-Fi 6, so your AP crashes). So the Wi-Fi network is gone until the AP finishes rebooting after it crashed. There shouldn't be a way for a client device, even a misbehaving one, to crash an AP. Fully update your AP's firmware, and if that doesn't fix it, consider running Linux firmware like OpenWrt on your AP, or getting a better AP.

Comment: @Spiff I can't update the AP's firmware because the wireless router was supplied by Optimum. I have already called them about the issue and they weren't sure what the problem is either. I could try asking them to replace the router though.